# forge.file.getVideo - Crashes on Android 4.3

Tags: android, crash, trigger.io

A simple call to forge.file.getVideo crashes my application when selecting the camera source. Running on Android 4.3.

My App crashes with empty callbacks for success and failure on forge.file.getVideo so I am assuming it is a trigger.io issue on Android 4.3

Comment: In our testing, I've found another bug with video capture on 4.3 - can you include your full log output (with debug output turned on), so that we can be sure we're talking about the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a bug in Nexus 4.3 devices, where all the fields of an intent being returned from another application are set to null.

We have a tentative workaround for this in our file module - I'll be checking that and hopefully deploying this week.